# Notation for two expressions with the same distribution

Tags: distributions, terminology, notation

Consider the situation when you have two expressions with the same distribution.
Is there any standard notation to express they have the same distribution?

An example:
$U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,2\pi)$, then $\cos(U)$ has the same distribution as $\sin(U)$. What is the cleanest, most intuitive way to express this mathematically?

I meant $\text{dist}(\cos(U)) = \text{dist}(\sin(U))$, but I assume there is something more standard.

Comment: dist is by default for distance (though there, you'd obviously have 2 arguments).

Comment: @Batman Yes, I know, but it wouldn't be the first occasion of ambiguous terminology on different fields.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Notation : $\cos(U) \stackrel d=\sin(U)$

If $X$ and $Y$ follow same distribution then mathematically you can write $X \stackrel d=Y$.